# int main(int argc, char* argv[]) and Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) with atoi(argv[1]); in Xcode

Tags: arrays, c, program-entry-point

I am new to programming in C and I am trying to write a program that reads in one command-line argument that is the size of an array. I get the error, Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) in Xcode.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])

int size = atoi(argv[1]);
```

This is a snippet of my program, in which I am using sorting functions with random values, but I need to read in the size of the array first.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you pass a command-line argument? In XCode or similar, it may need to specified in a configuration dialog if running via the tool itself.

Comment: *Always* check `argc` before accessing `argv`. [what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean)

Answer (score 0):

The "null" value you are getting almost definitely means that you are reading past the end of the `argv` array. For example if I run a program as:
`myprogram hello world`

- `argc` will be 3
- `argv[0]` will be "myprogram"
- `argv[1]` will be "hello"
- `argv[2]` will be "world"
- `argv[3]` is undefined and you should not even attempt to read the array here! (but will *probably* be NULL in most environments so that programs crash predictably)

Always check that the index for `argv` is less than `argc` since array indexes in C start at 0.

Comment: I'm still confused on how to check the index for argv is less than argc, but if I go to the Products->Scheme->Edit Scheme->Run->Arguments->Arguments Passed On Launch in Xcode, and enter a value, the program runs fine. Do you have to adjust argc or argv (probably argv) somehow?

Comment: No, the C runtime and OS sets up those variables for you based on the parameters passed to your program. As Anton K puts it below, you have to check that the `argv[]` index you want is less than `argc`.

Answer (score 0):

the char* argv[] is an array of strings (usually used as char** argv)
and the argc is amount of parameter when the 0 parameter is the program name, 1 is first parameter, 2 is second and etc.

you need to check that index of argv (named paramIndexThatIWant) less then argc

for example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
      int paramIndexThatIWant = 2; /* param index that i want to use */
      if(argc > paramIndexThatIWant )
      {
           printf("> Param %i equal value %s.\n",paramIndexThatIWant, argv[paramIndexThatIWant]);
      }
      else
      {
           printf("No parameter at pos %i, argc is %i\n", paramIndexThatIWant, argc);
      }
      return 0;
}
```

again remember that argc count the program name itself as one, so if you have one parameter only so its value will be one, this is why in the example i have just one param, argc equal to 2 but but argv[2] not exist.

[image]